# PHP Variable Statement At End of SQL Query Produces Error Flag SQL Dialects

Tags: phpstorm

I have SQL Dialects enabled for my project.  I am using the below code

[image]

There is a PHP variable that is set if a certain condition is met.  SQL Dialects thinks there is an error at the end of the SQL statement since it expects either a GROUP BY, HAVING, or other SQL declaration after the WHERE declaration.  It underlines the variable and the entire file is marked as having known syntax errors.  Is there a way for me to create an exception in SQL Dialects so this is ignored?

Comment: may i advice you to initialise your $sql_statement_add_on to '', and to write it inside the query as ${sql_statement_add_on} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inspection is performed by Database Support module:

1. which knows nothing about PHP variables;
2. this is not a valid SQL from that specific dialect point of view (MySQL/SQL Server/whatever).

Your only choice ATM is to use **"Keywords Only"** as SQL Dialect where only basic syntax highlighting will be available.

Other than that:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2450
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7594
- somehow related http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2324

Comment: I read through the issues links.  This is a real bummer since I am very fond of the auto-completion function