# PHPStorm warnings on placeholders in WordPress plugin queries

Tags: mysql, wordpress, prepared-statement, phpstorm

I have a WordPress plugin that I am editing in PHPStorm. PHPStorm finds syntax errors on queries like this when the SQL dialect is set to MySQL:

```
$foo = $wpdb->get_var(
           $wpdb->prepare(
               'SELECT `foo` FROM `some_table` WHERE `id` = %d',
               $bar
           )
       );
```

Specifically, it sees `%d` and complains with this message:

```
<expression> expected, got '%'
```

Of course, `%d` is a perfectly legitimate placeholder in WordPress queries.  Is there a way to configure PHPStorm to accept this? Or do I have to disable all checks on SQL statements, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18882399/2057919)?

Note that I am using PHPStorm EAP 8 (138.1751), and the same thing happens with other placeholders like `%s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now possible in PHPStorm 8, as explained by this post on the official PHPStorm blog:

[Database Language Injection Configuration](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/11/database-language-injection-configuration/)

To solve it:

- Go to Tools > Databases
- Make sure a regex matching the placeholders in question is in the list of custom parameters. By default, the list includes `\%\w+`, which will match `%s`, `%d`, etc.
- Check the box labeled "Use in other language string literals"

PHPStorm will now correctly recognize placeholders like those used in WordPress.

Comment: Note for later versions (2018.1), the setting is located at File -> Settings -> Tools -> Database -> User Parameters. Click the green plus sign on the right, for pattern put `\%\w+` (other items will have quotes, but this one must not!). Check "In scripts" and "In literals" checkboxes, and for the language select *PHP*

Answer (score 2):

Nope -- `%d` is not valid syntax from SQL point of view (ANY currently supported dialect). The [WI-3672](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3672) and [WI-2324](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2324) tickets are **still** valid.

But PhpStorm v8 now supports `$var` (if you could use it instead of `%` syntax) -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2450

---

Since it's WordPress specific question, it's hard for me to give you any real suggestion (especially since I'm not using WordPress myself) excluding [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18882399/2057919).

But generally speaking you could use native place holders supported by specific DB engine (check "Examples" section in http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

- unnamed `?`
- named `:id`

I just not sure if this can be applied to WordPress development.

---

**P.S.**
`Generic` is the new `Keywords only` dialect -- fall back to that if using proper SQL dialect shows to many warnings/errors (that are not actual errors).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware it's non-standard SQL syntax. I think it was WordPress's attempt to handle prepared statements before MySQLi and PDO came along. But [it's what I'm stuck with for now](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders) unless I roll my own database connection using PDO or MySQLi. Using a literal variable like `$var` won't work, because it prevents any kind of parameterization (I would have to add a lot more data validation, conversion, and escaping than I currently have). And "Keywords Only" is no longer available as a dialect, so I'm not even sure I can use that.

Comment: Try "Generic" instead of "Keywords only".

Comment: Well, I was 100% sure I had tried that, but apparently not. I had to turn off the "SQL dialect detection" code inspection to make PHPStorm happy about my use of "Generic" as the dialect. Unfortunately, that seems to basically disable *all* SQL checks; it thinks that `SELECT WHERE foo FROM bar` looks just fine. It seems like this is the best I can do for now, though, so it you add your comment to your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Well -- "Generic" is the new "Keywords only"